# AttributeError: This method is available only on the class, not on instances. Django Viewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am writing a simple django app where all my apis are based on class based viewsets. I've the following viewset with 2 methods(2 different api calls) but in one of the apis i wanted to access another api's method.

```
class TestViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
   queryset = Model.objects.all()
   serializer_class = MSerializer

   @action(detail=True, methods=["PUT"], name="viewone")
   def viewone(self, request, pk):
       try:
           <logic>
        except Exception as e:
           raise("error")
  @action(detail=True, methods=["PUT"], name="viewtwo")
  def viewtwo(self, request, pk):
       try:
           viewone = self.as_view({'put': 'viewone'})(request, pk=pk)
           <viewtwo-logic>
        except Exception as e:
           print(e) 
           raise("error")
```

the view set two throws me the following

```
AttributeError: This method is available only on the class, not on instances.
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you simply _call_ the method? `viewone = self.viewone(request, pk=pk)`?...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat tried and got the following 
viewone = self. viewone(request, pk=pk)
 api response is ::: <Response status_code=400, "text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: sorry. mistake from my end it actually works  @AbdulAzizBarkat!

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Abdul Aziz Barkat is the answer

```
viewone = self.viewone(request, pk=pk)
```